# ERROR 1083 (42000) at line 1: Field separator argument is not what is expected when using mysql LOAD

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-loadfile

I am trying to use mysql load via the shell prompt. I want to load a CSV file directly into the database.

`mysql -u root -p -h mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'Subscriber.csv' INTO TABLE temp_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 ROWS" psi`

I am getting the error `ERROR 1083 (42000) at line 1: Field separator argument is not what is expected`

Below is my CSV file

`misdn,city,age,gender
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,24,MALE
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,32,MALE
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,37,Male
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,36,MALE
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,25,Male
771XXXXXX,HWEDZA,26,MALE
771XXXXXX,HWEDZA,33,MALE
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,26,MALE
771XXXXXX,HWEDZA,34,MALE
771XXXXXX,HWEDZA,34,MALE
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,21,MALE
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,22,MALE
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,30,MALE
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,28,Male
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,33,Male
771XXXXXX,MUTOKO,23,Male
771XXXXXX,ZVISHAVANE,31,Male
771XXXXXX,ZVISHAVANE,39,MALE`

Please help, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the first 2-3 lines of `Subscriber.csv`.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question and added the CSV file

Comment: your fields arn't enclosed try removing `ENCLOSED BY '"'` or use `ENCLOSED BY ''`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used `ENCLOSED BY '"'`, but your fields do not contain double quotes at all.  I think you should have used `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`.  Try this version:

```
mysql -u root -p -h mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'Subscriber.csv'
    INTO TABLE temp_data
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 ROWS" psi
```

Or, if you are certain that no fields will ever have double quotes, you could remove the `ENCLOSED BY` clause entirely.